# Warning message of dropping repeat detection's in secr package

Tags: r, spatial

I am getting this warning message in the secr package. I am new to using secr and cannot figure out what all can cause this warning.

> Warning message: In make.capthist(captures = capturelist[[i]], traps =
> trps, fmt = fmt,  :   dropping repeat detections within occasions at
> exclusive detectors (traps)

I am having a hard time trying to figure out what is causing it. At first, I did have some duplicate detections within the data frame but I have fixed those errors, which I thought would fix this problem. I have also re-run everything after I fixed those errors. There should be no duplicates anywhere. My next thought would be because my Occasions are labeled similar but that didn't seem like a problem for the example vignettes in the secr package. Down below, I will post some chunks of my data frame and the code I used so you can get an idea of what I am working with, please let me know if you need more.
Cap3 is the capture data

```
structure(list(comb = c("BLAA1", "BLAA2", "BLAA3", "BLAA4", "BLAA5", 
"BLAA6", "BLAA7", "BLAA8", "BLAA9", "BLAA10", "BLAA11", "BLAA12", 
"BLAA13", "BLAA14", "BLAA15", "BLAA16", "BLAA17", "BLAA18", "BLAA19", 
"BLAA20"), x = c(594488.009017769, 594494.454131318, 594500.925688313, 
594506.662261498, 594513.257586228, 594519.322688487, 594525.327166843, 
594494.416877132, 594500.949900257, 594507.305003891, 594513.462996849, 
594519.318415089, 594526.022352206, 594493.949850101, 594500.514008217, 
594506.077750325, 594512.611547263, 594519.35292817, 594526.294412644, 
594532.525743323), y = c(4162274.11803146, 4162281.70044966, 
4162289.54357038, 4162297.63242269, 4162304.81340058, 4162312.42590495, 
4162320.11502766, 4162274.56651945, 4162282.25868995, 4162290.17150489, 
4162297.38152451, 4162305.21467498, 4162313.24355778, 4162266.64317363, 
4162274.18626698, 4162281.61291192, 4162289.41643482, 4162297.0022523, 
4162304.74237878, 4162313.13131802)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(head(cap3,20))
structure(list(Session = c("Jag_1", "Jag_1", "Jag_1", "Jag_1", 
"Jag_1", "Jag_1", "Jag_1", "Jag_1", "Jag_1", "Jag_1", "Jag_1", 
"Bla_1", "Bla_1", "Bla_1", "Bla_1", "Bla_1", "Bla_1", "Bla_1", 
"Lon_1", "Lon_1"), ID = c(9460838L, 9460784L, 1234573L, 9460831L, 
9460845L, 9460838L, 9460794L, 9460785L, 9460784L, 9460781L, 9460777L, 
9460780L, 2055339L, 9460813L, 9460782L, 9460786L, 9460782L, 9460786L, 
9460810L, 9460834L), Occasion = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1), Detector = c("JAGB60", "JAGB57", 
"JAGB27", "JAGA55", "JAGC52", "JAGB53", "JAGB85", "JAGC66", "JAGB79", 
"JAGB37", "JAGA81", "BLAC64", "BLAB81", "BLAC77", "BLAC76", "BLAC11", 
"BLAC64", "BLAC19", "LONB11", "LONC73"), Species = c("Perm.", 
"Perm.", "Mico.", "Mico.", "Perm.", "Perm.", "Perm.", "Perm.", 
"Perm.", "Perm.", "Perl.", "Perm.", "Perm.", "Perm.", "Perm.", 
"Perm.", "Perm.", "Perm.", "Perm.", "Perm."), Gender = c("M", 
"F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Detector is the detector layout

```
structure(list(comb = c("BLAA1", "BLAA2", "BLAA3", "BLAA4", "BLAA5", 
"BLAA6", "BLAA7", "BLAA8", "BLAA9", "BLAA10", "BLAA11", "BLAA12", 
"BLAA13", "BLAA14", "BLAA15", "BLAA16", "BLAA17", "BLAA18", "BLAA19", 
"BLAA20"), x = c(594488.009017769, 594494.454131318, 594500.925688313, 
594506.662261498, 594513.257586228, 594519.322688487, 594525.327166843, 
594494.416877132, 594500.949900257, 594507.305003891, 594513.462996849, 
594519.318415089, 594526.022352206, 594493.949850101, 594500.514008217, 
594506.077750325, 594512.611547263, 594519.35292817, 594526.294412644, 
594532.525743323), y = c(4162274.11803146, 4162281.70044966, 
4162289.54357038, 4162297.63242269, 4162304.81340058, 4162312.42590495, 
4162320.11502766, 4162274.56651945, 4162282.25868995, 4162290.17150489, 
4162297.38152451, 4162305.21467498, 4162313.24355778, 4162266.64317363, 
4162274.18626698, 4162281.61291192, 4162289.41643482, 4162297.0022523, 
4162304.74237878, 4162313.13131802)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then this was the code I ran with both of those data frames

```
detector %<>% 
  as.data.frame()
trap <- read.traps(data = detector, detector = 'single', trapID = 'comb')
test1 <- make.capthist(captures = cap3, traps = trap)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error in secr 4.3.3. [This discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/secrgroup/c/rUaXl4Dli2E) says that it is a bug, so first you should update your secr to 4.3.4 or later. I still got the error after the update, and careful searching found that I did have one animal captured twice in one session so I need to go back to the data sheets to figure that out.

Comment: is this a comment?

Comment: I believe updating to secr 4.3.4 or later will solve the problem. If it needs to be a comment, would that require deleting the answer?

Comment: I consider this a partial answer in the absence of a full answer - which is fine.